# Failed to install error message when I try any extension install

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to install any Visual Studio Code extension I get error message "Failed to install" with a button to download manually. I tried install manually and it work but why installing from extensions menu give me this error ?

I tried also to disable Norton Security firewall and auto protect but problem remain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it was a DNS problem when I used Google or OpenDNS problem solved.

OpenDNS, 2019208.67.222.222 · 208.67.220.220